# Display menu items of unpublished nodes to users without "Administer Content" permission

Tags: 7, routes

I have a content editor who is building out a section. All the nodes are yet unpublished. The problem is unpublished nodes are not displayed in a menu. While this is correct behavior with a user viewing a site, the editing experience is lacking in that way. How can I build a representation of a menu of unpublished items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using a module called [Menu view unpublished](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_view_unpublished) which is a ...

> Small module that allows users to view menu links to unpublished nodes.
>
> The menu system from Drupal core hides menu links that link to nodes
> that are unpublished. This modules provides a permission that undoes
> this behavior, but only if the user has access to view the
> (unpublished) node.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, by default the menu items are shown when the path is accessible.
So if the menu item is enabled and point to an unpublished node, it won't be visible to anonymous users but should be visible to privileged users (with 'administer content' permission, for example).

Edit: [view_unpublished](https://www.drupal.org/project/view_unpublished) module may work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) to make a list of all unpublished nodes. That way it is easy for people to find pages they are working on.